# Your own managed bean and type ahead

Tags: xpages

If I create my own managed bean is it possible to get the type ahead to work in Domino Designer with my own Bean / Java Code?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Maybe a special code assistant plugin or anything similar?

Comment: No, typeahead in SSJS code doesn't work in this version of Domino Designer. You need to write all code in Java to get the typeahead to work.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to keep digging: When you say "in this version", what version are you refering to? 8.5.x? Does it work in 9.0.x then?

Comment: No it doesn't work in any existing version, but perhaps IBM will fix this in the next version of Domino designer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a MB DebugHelper. As you can see from the screenshot, it shows the bean method debugPrint() as soon as I type the dot.  Is this, what you asked for? 
[image]

Comment: I think Fredrik is looking for typeahead in the XSP source editor and the SSJS editor

Comment: ah, I see, SSJS. I'm to focussed on Java :)